# Ending an infinite loop issue (Python)

Tags: python, loops

I am attempting to create a loop which a user can stop at the end of the program. I've tried various solutions, none of which have worked, all I have managed to do is create the loop but I can't seem to end it. I only recently started learning Python and I would be grateful if someone could enlighten me on this issue.

```
def main():
 while True:
    NoChild = int(0)
    NoAdult = int(0)
    NoDays  = int(0)
    AdultCost = int(0)
    ChildCost = int(0)
    FinalCost = int(0)


    print ("Welcome to Superslides!")
    print ("The theme park with the biggest water slide in Europe.")

    NoAdult = int(raw_input("How many adults are there?"))
    NoChild = int(raw_input("How many children are there?"))
    NoDays  = int(raw_input("How many days will you be at the theme park?"))
    WeekDay = (raw_input("Will you be attending the park on a weekday? (Yes/No)"))

    if WeekDay == "Yes":
        AdultCost = NoAdult * 5

    elif WeekDay == "No":
        AdultCost = NoAdult * 10

    ChildCost = NoChild * 5

    FinalCost = (AdultCost + ChildCost)*NoDays

    print ("Order Summary")
    print("Number of Adults: ",NoAdult,"Cost: ",AdultCost)
    print("Number of Children: ",NoChild,"Cost: ",ChildCost)
    print("Your final total is:",FinalCost)
    print("Have a nice day at SuperSlides!")

    again = raw_input("Would you like to process another customer? (Yes/No)")
    if again =="No":
        print("Goodbye!")
        return
    elif again =="Yes":
        print("Next Customer.")

    else:
        print("You should enter either Yes or No.")

if __name__=="__main__":
main()
```

Comment: When would you expect your program to end and what is it doing instead? Also, there are several problems - you're using Python 3's `print()` function syntax together with Python 2's `raw_input()`. No need for all those `var = int(0)` lines - you don't have to initialize variables in Python. What should happen if the user answers neither `Yes` nor `No` to the first question?

Comment: I tried using break but the loop continued to run.

Comment: Replace return with break.

Comment: `return` would work instead of `break`, that's not the problem. Did you really enter `No` in exactly that spelling (uppercase `N`, lowercase `o`)?

Comment: When I expect the program to end it just doesn't and continues to cycle through the entire program. Also thank you for the advice!

Comment: I ran your program (unchanged) and it terminated as expected. Make sure you're typing `No` with a capital `N` and a lowercase `o`

Comment: Thanks, it worked when I used "No" exactly. I didn't think it would be case sensitive, oops.

Comment: If you don't want it to be case senstive, you can check `if again.lower() == 'no'`

Answer (score 0):

You can change the return to break and it will exit the while loop

```
if again =="No":
    print("Goodbye!")
    break
```

Comment: I'm not sure that's the problem.

Comment: `return` will end the function all, breaking the loop as well. There is no need for `break`

Comment: Correct but using break allows for more to be done in __main__

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

```
while True:
```

You should use this:

```
again = True
while again:
    ...

    usrIn = raw_input("Would you like to process another customer? y/n")
    if usrIn == 'y':
        again = True
    else
        again = False
```

I just made it default to False, but you can always just make it ask the user for a new input if they don't enter y or n.

Answer (score 0):

I checked your code with python 3.5 and it worked after I changed the `raw_input` to `input`, since input in 3.5 is the raw_input of 2.7. Since you're using print() as a function, you should have an import of the print function from future package in your import section. I can't see no import section in your script.

What exactly doesn't work?

Additionally: It's a good habit to end a command line application by exiting with an exit code instead of breaking and ending. So you would have to

```
import sys
```

in the import section of your python script and when checking for ending the program by the user, do a

```
if again == "No":
   print("Good Bye")
   sys.exit(0)
```

This gives you the opportunity in case of an error to exit with a different exit code.

Answer (score 0):

Change this code snippet

```
if again =="No":
        print("Goodbye!")
        exit() #this will close the program
    elif again =="Yes":
        print("Next Customer.")
        exit()#this will close the program
    else:
        print("You should enter either Yes or No.")
```